# Multi-threaded 'fixed'

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory, parallel-processing, fixed

I have a huge array that is being analyzed differently by two threads:

- Data is large-  no copies allowed
- Threads must process concurrently
- Must disable bounds checking for maximum performance

Therefore, each thread looks something like this:

```
unsafe void Thread(UInt16[] data)
{
  fixed(UInt16* pData = data)
  {
    UInt16* pDataEnd = pData + data.Length;
    for(UInt16* pCur=pData; pCur != pDataEnd; pCur++)
    {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Since there is no mutex (*intentionally*),  I'm wondering if it's safe to use two **fixed** statements on the same data on parallel threads??  Presumably the second fixed should return the same pointer as the first, because memory is already pinned...  and when the first completes, it won't really unpin memory because there is a second fixed() still active.. Has anyone tried this scenario?

Comment: Please consider adjusting your question's title to contain more than just the tags. It should contain some contextual detail to help users that might help know they should be interested.

Comment: And you're really sure you need the pointers?  fixing a large block for a longer time is a burden on the GC.

Comment: @M.Babcock - as long as your read 'fixed' the right way the title is spot on.

Comment: What's your "do stuff" logic like?

Comment: Why not fix the data before passing it as argument?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: If the block is that big, it'll be in the LOH and would effectively be fixed anyway.

Comment: Data size is 20MB or more.. Redundant input copies are bad because each analysis may allocate hundreds MB for scratch buffers. Can't pin before launching the thread-  impossible. "Do stuff" operations are read-only and data will never change once generated, so sync is not needed. Maybe I should adjust the tags, because the title was written first.

Comment: Array bounds checks are usually removed by the JIT compiler as long nothing weird is going on inside the loop.  Just curious...what was the performance difference between safe and unsafe code?

Comment: @Gabe: see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) : _if you allocate large objects and want to make sure they don't move, you should still pin them_

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I'm not saying he shouldn't pin the array; I'm saying that pinning a 20MB object isn't a burden on the GC because the current garbage collector would never try to compact an object that large.

Comment: Henk thanks for the link.  Useful info. In particular:  _"This means the allocation cost of a large object is completely dominated by memory clearing (unless it triggers a garbage collection). For a 16MB object on a 2Ghz machine, it will take approximately 16ms to clear the memory"_.   So I'm probably adding an additional 25ms or more for each allocation. That's **inane**.  I'm probably adding 0.5sec to each full cycle for worthless overhead.  **AllocHGlobal** it is, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of using fixed, you could use GCHandle.Alloc to pin the array:

```
// not inside your thread, but were you init your shared array
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(anArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr intPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();


// your thread
void Worker(IntPtr pArray)
{
  unsafe
  {
     UInt16* ptr = (UInt16*) pArray.ToPointer();
      ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to "CLR via C#" it is safe to do so.

The compiler sets a 'pinned' flag on `pData` variable (on the pointer, not on the array instance).

So multiple/recursive use should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is

```
 for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
 {
     // do stuff with data[i]
 }
```

the bounds check is eliminated by the JIT compiler. So no need for unsafe code.

Note that this does not hold if your access pattern is more complex than that.

Comment: I didn't mention in the original, but unfortunately this is impossible because  "DoStuff"  might actually be a call to unmanaged library.  I █ pixels, too.